# Problem adding loading icon with TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi team i have a problem when im trying to add a loading icon and the problem is this. Wen i loading the webservice the icon is showed but inmediatly desapear and the webservice it takes about 6 second do show all data.... here is my code.

```
public loadData(): void {
        dataModel = new TimelineStructure();
        this.dataManager = new RoadmapDataManager(dataModel, this, this.underlyingModelService, this.commonService);
        // Visualization starts always first day of month.
        dataModel.originDate = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        // dataModel.originDate = moment().format().valueOf();

        this.startLoading();
        const call: Promise<McDataResponse<Swimlane>> = this.underlyingModelService.getSwimlanes(this.journeyId).toPromise();
        call.then(data => {
            const swimlanes: any[] = (data.data as []);
            let countdown = swimlanes.length;
            let count = 0;
            swimlanes.forEach(swimlane => {
                const task: Task = TaskParser.parser(swimlane, count++);
                dataModel.tasks.push(task);
                dataModel.unfilteredTasks.push(task);
                this.setSwimlaneAssignee(task);
                this.underlyingModelService.getSwimlaneItems(swimlane.id).subscribe(
                    dataItem => {
                        const items: any[] = (dataItem.data as []);
                        items.forEach(i => {
                            const activity: Activity = this.activityParser.parser(i, swimlane.index);
                            if (i.label === 'Plan') {
                                this.underlyingModelService.countTasks(i.projectId).subscribe(
                                    response => {
                                        this.activityEmpty = response.data[0] === 0;
                                        activity.isEmpty = response.data[0] === 0;
                                        dataModel.activities.push(activity);
                                        dataModel.unfilteredActivities.push(activity);
                                        this.setPlanAssignee(activity);
                                        this.destroyAndReload();
                                    });
                            } else {
                                dataModel.activities.push(activity);
                                dataModel.unfilteredActivities.push(activity);
                            }
                        });

                        if (--countdown === 0) {
                            this.loadGanttChart(this.primaryPeriod, this.secondaryPeriod);
                            this.destroyAndReload();
                        }
                    });
            });
            this.createMarker();
        }).finally(() => {
            this.stopLoading();
        });
    }
```

the function that do start loading icon is StartLoading and is a sample boolean variable that i use in my html file

Comment: and what is that boolean variable you use in the HTML file? (: can we see it in the TypeScript excerpt provided? (:

Comment: yes is this :

``public startLoading() {
        this.loading = true;
    }

    public stopLoading() {
        this.loading = false;
    }``

Comment: posted a answer below, please check.

Answer (score 2):

The  problem in the above code was that the promise got resolved even before the inner api gets complete which you are subscribing to. Actually there is no need of changing the code into a promised.  Your Code should look something like this :-

```
public loadData(): void {
        dataModel = new TimelineStructure();
        this.dataManager = new RoadmapDataManager(dataModel, this, this.underlyingModelService, this.commonService);
        // Visualization starts always first day of month.
        dataModel.originDate = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        // dataModel.originDate = moment().format().valueOf();

        this.startLoading();
        const call: Observable<McDataResponse<Swimlane>> = this.underlyingModelService.getSwimlanes(this.journeyId);
        call.pipe(mergeMap(data => {
            const swimlanes: any[] = (data.data as []);
            let countdown = swimlanes.length;
            let count = 0;
            const swimLaneCalls = swimlanes.map((swimlane)=>this.underlyingModelService.getSwinlaneItems(swinlane.id).pipe(mergeMap(dataItem => {
                        const items: any[] = (dataItem.data as []);
                        const myCalls = [];
                        items.forEach(i => {
                            const activity: Activity = this.activityParser.parser(i, swimlane.index);
                            if (i.label === 'Plan') {
                                myCalls.push(this.underlyingModelService.countTasks(i.projectId).pipe(map(
                                    response => {
                                        this.activityEmpty = response.data[0] === 0;
                                        activity.isEmpty = response.data[0] === 0;
                                        dataModel.activities.push(activity);
                                        dataModel.unfilteredActivities.push(activity);
                                        this.setPlanAssignee(activity);
                                        this.destroyAndReload();
                                    })));
                            } else {
                                dataModel.activities.push(activity);
                                dataModel.unfilteredActivities.push(activity);
                            }
                        });
                        return forkJoin(mycalls).pipe(map(()=> {
                if (--countdown === 0) {
                                    this.loadGanttChart(this.primaryPeriod, this.secondaryPeriod);
                                    this.destroyAndReload();
                            }
                        });
                      })));
            swimlanes.forEach(swimlane => {
                const task: Task = TaskParser.parser(swimlane, count++);
                dataModel.tasks.push(task);
                dataModel.unfilteredTasks.push(task);
                this.setSwimlaneAssignee(task);
            });
            return forkJoin(swimLaneCalls).pipe(map(res=> {
                 this.createMarker();
            });
        })).subscribe(() => {
            this.stopLoading();
        });
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your coment but im trying do use yor code and giving me the next errors.
 ERROR in GanttChartDemo.ts(382,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Observable'.
    GanttChartDemo.ts(383,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'mergeMap'.
    GanttChartDemo.ts(387,89): error TS2551: Property 'getSwinlaneItems' does not exist on type 'UnderlyingModelService'. Did you mean 'getSwimlaneItems'?

Comment: GanttChartDemo.ts(387,106): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'swinlane'. Did you mean 'swimlane'?
    GanttChartDemo.ts(387,124): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'mergeMap'.
    GanttChartDemo.ts(393,95): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?
    GanttChartDemo.ts(407,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'forkJoin'.
    GanttChartDemo.ts(407,33): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'mycalls'. Did you mean 'myCalls'?
    GanttChartDemo.ts(407,47): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?

Comment: GanttChartDemo.ts(420,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'forkJoin'.
    GanttChartDemo.ts(420,49): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?

Comment: map, forkjoin, mermgemap are rxjs operators. You need to import them

Comment: you imported all operators?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214664/discussion-between-aakash-garg-and-nikolai-ivanov).

Comment: come in chat please?

Comment: yes change swinlane to swimlane. mycalls to myCalls. getSwinlaneItems to getSwimlaneItems